# Why should I use formlayout/formdata instead of setBounds?

Tags: java, layout, swt

When creating something as simple as a `Combo`, why should I use `FormLayout` with `FormData` instead of settings the bounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using layouts makes it easier to support different OSes, user settings, resolutions. It also helps to better handle window resizes. E.g. different OSes have different font sizes (or some users may set different default fonts) - so the text may be clipped if you don't test your UI on all possible settings.